# Validation Bootstrap datepicker with specific format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a problem with a bootstrap datepicker and I couldn't solve it yet. I hope you guys have an idea.

I added both references bootstrap-datepicker.js and datepicker.css on my page. Then I defined the date format of my input by jquery.

```
$('#DataNascimento').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

//My View
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataNascimento, new { @class = "datepicker", @data_mask = "99/99/9999", @data_date=Model.DataNascimento, data_date_format=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, @data_val_date = "Informe uma Data de Nascimento válida" })

//My Web.config
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>
```

Although I type a correct date format (dd/MM/yyyy) I always get the error message "Date format invalid".
I already tried to remove the attributes @data_mask, @data_date, @data_date_format and @data_val_date of the TextBox but it's still not working.
Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4

**UPDATE:**

Guys, I have tested the app in another browsers (Firefox and IE) and I don't have the same problem on them. I believe that it's a issue on Chrome. I already changed the attribute "lang" of my html code from 'en' to 'pt-br' but it's still not working on chrome.
As @TrueBlueAussie suggested, I'll try to create a test project and test it again.
Thanks!

Comment: I was have same problem. Is programming in that language? ASP?

Comment: Is this looks like Razor code, can you show server-side code where you are receiving & validating the data and storing it? (or is this purely a client side validation error?)

Comment: Yes, razor code. I didn't see `@Html.TextBoxFor`. I had have exacly error. I'll construct answer

Comment: I changed the date format to 'dd/mm/yy' but it's still not working.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I'm not doing any type of server side validation. I just created the attribute "DataNascimento" as a DateTime, created the field as a TextBoxFor and defined it as a datepicker.

Comment: I have recreated all details of your example in a new MVC 5 project, but I am not getting your error. I can use mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy and get the correct results in each. The client side format is independent of the server locale. What versions of bootstrap and bootstrap-datepicker are you using? I know the older versions did not support locale very well.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie maybe is the version MVC project

Comment: @CesarMiguel: The technology involved is all client-side, so I doubt it is MVC.

Comment: @Deise Vicentin: I have just tried my prototype on all the main browsers and  it works fine, so I can only suggest creating a new test project, with the latest tools, and test it stand-alone. If you can create a small test project that does not work and upload it somewhere I will be happy to test it for problems here (I have all versions of Visual Studio available so does not matter which).

Answer (score 0):

I had exacly error. This answer contains the steps I follow

1º - Create another text box with atribute hidden:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { @class = "hidden"})`

2º - Text Box to manipulate date inserted from datapicker:

`@Html.TextBox("DataNascimentoManipulate", null, new { @class = "datepicker"}`

3º - Now manipulate date

`

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }).on('changeDate', function () {
            if ($("#DataNascimentoManipulate").val() != "") {
                var varData = $("#DataNascimentoManipulate").val().split("/");
                var NovaData = "" + varData[2] + "/" + varData[1] + "/" + varData[0];
                $("#DataNascimento").val(NovaData);
            }
```

`

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work for me. :( But I found out that the same code I posted works in Firefox...I think the problem is with my browser.